# I can install Nvidia driver v340 but not v430. However, my GPU supports v430. Help please?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus

Note:
1) I've alrdy ran the command "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa".
2) I've alrdy selected Nvidia GPU using prime-select (CLI) / prime profile (GUI).
3) I tried with v418 and end up with the same result as v430.
4) Running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
5) I've tried rebooting almost after every steps too.
6) Purged nvidia completely before each new installation.
7) Disabled Secure Boot.

I've been trying to install Nvidia driver version 430, however, when I run the command "nvidia-smi", the output will always tell me that the driver NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

Running nvidia-smi on v340 will not have the same output above. Instead, the proper gpu related output table will show up.

Additional Notes: My computer is running GPU Nvidia Geforce 820M which supports 430. However, in Software & Updates, only nouveau and Nvidia v340 is listed. I've checked in Nvidia's website and my GPU supports v430.
[Screenshot: Additional Driver in Software & Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwsyO.png)

Comment: If installing a different nVidia driver, you must purge old or else you will have conflicts. https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers Shows purge commands & how to just install one specific version.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. I've alrdy purged nvidia completely before each nvidia driver installation.

Answer (score 0):

I use [ubuntu-drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) to install cuda drivers for ubuntu.

If you have ppa setup, you can update to 430. Without ppa, the latest version right now supported by ubuntu-drivers is 390. [They will update the latest version to 430, once the testing is done](https://youtu.be/NFdeWTQIpjo).
Let ubuntu update its list via `sudo apt update`. 
See which drivers are compatible `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`

You might see an output like

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==

vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000DDAsv000017AAsd000021D1bc03sc00i00
model    : GF106GLM [Quadro 2000M]
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-331 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-331-updates - distro non-free
```

Install the update via `sudo apt install nvidia-xxx` where xxx is the driver version.